# Mesh flickering in 2.8

Tags: mesh

So I recently updated to 2.8 and I'm having trouble with meshes when trying to edit them. The lines aren't even in thickness and at certain angles can disappear. Then when moving about the whole thing flickers. It happens even if I just load up a new file and add a simple sphere:

[image]

Is there some sort of setting I need to stop this happening? I've been trying to just put up with it the past week but it's quite a strain on the eyes!

Answer (score 1):

Disable Anti Aliasing in *Preferences > Viewport > Quality > Viewport Anti-Aliasing* and choose *No Anti Aliasing*